# how to save featured data into featured table from product table in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I hope you are doing well. I am new in codeigniter :::

I have two tables in database 1. tbl_product  2. tbl_featured_products. I get data from tbl_product in a form with foreach loop in checkbox system. After that I need to save product data into  tbl_featured_products. I can not save it (multiple data in row ).... please help me out ..

My Question:: 
1. how can I save data into tbl_featured_products ?
2. how can I show image and others info and save data from view page ?

Controller:::

```
    $data=array();

    $data['featured_id']=$this->input->post('featured_id',true);
    $data['product_id']=$this->input->post('product_id',true);
    $data['product_name']=$this->input->post('product_name',true);
    $data['product_price']=$this->input->post('product_price',true);
    $data['product_image']=$this->input->post('product_image',true);

    $this->sa_model->save_featured_product_info($data);
}
```

Model :::::

```
public function save_featured_product_info($data)
{
    $this->db->insert('tbl_featured_products',$data);
}
```

view::::

```
    <tr>
        <td width="130">Product Name: </td>

        <td>

            <?php foreach($all_product as $values) { ?>
                <input type="checkbox" name="product_name" value="<?php echo $values->product_name;?>"> <?php echo $values->product_name;?> <br>

            <?php } ?>

        </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: You said you need to save `multiple data in row`? There is no loop in your controller or in your model. Why? Its just saving a single row. Post your form too.

Comment: Yes. you are right. I have failed to do that. Would you please like to provide me a sample code or instruction that I can learn from them ?? please

Comment: you are welcome to learn from here http://net.tutsplus.com/sessions/codeigniter-from-scratch/ or here http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/

Comment: thanks for you reply. would you please help me out with this issues ? please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try the following: 
first load data to your view

Controller:

```
function dataToView(){
   $data = $this->sa_model->tbl_product_info($data); //gets information from your model db 
   $this->load->view('templates/home', $data); //sends data to the view
}
```

View:

```
<tr>
    <td width="130">Product Name: </td>

    <td>
        <form id="product_form">
        <?php foreach($all_product as $values) { ?>
            <input type="checkbox" name="product_name" value="<?php echo $values->product_name;?>"> <?php echo $values->product_name;?> <br>
        <?php } ?>
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Javascript

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#product_form').submit(function(){
            var url = 'controller/save';
            $.post(url, function(result){
                if (result){
                    //...your success function..
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });

</script>
```

Controller

```
<?php
function save(){
    $product = $this->input->post('product_name');//this will get your posted product into the controller
    //...add your own function
    if (works){
        echo true;
    }else{
        echo false;
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: It is not working. Please let me know the correct one. Thanks

Comment: what do you have so far? are you able to load all your data to your view?

Comment: yes ... I am able to load data to view file... I want to save multiple data in another table with product_id

Comment: in that case, add the javascript i posted above and make the url point to your controller's method. This method will then cache all your post input so that you can store them in the db using your model. Were you able to get this far?

Comment: data is not saving in table.. please help me out